# How to create a nested relationship with a nested relationship

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have created several Entities and want to properly combine them into one using nested relations. When I Build the Application I get this error:

> TrainingWithExerciseWithSets.java:13: error: There is a problem with the query: SQL error or missing database (no such column: exerciseName)

How to fix it?

My data classes:

Set:

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "set_table",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Training::class,
            parentColumns = ["trainingId"],
            childColumns = ["trainingId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = SetType::class,
            parentColumns = ["setTypeId"],
            childColumns = ["setTypeId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL,
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Exercise::class,
            parentColumns = ["exerciseId"],
            childColumns = ["exerciseId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
        )
    ]
)
@Parcelize
data class Set(
    val trainingId: Long,
    val setTypeId: Long,
    val exerciseId: Long,
    val minimum: Int,
    val maximum: Int,
    val restTime: Int? = null,
    val repsInReserve: Int? = null
) : BaseEntity, Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var setId: Long = 0
}
```

Set Type

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "set_type_table")
@Parcelize
data class SetType(val setTypeName: String) : BaseEntity, Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var setTypeId: Long = 0
}
```

Exercise:

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "exercise_table",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = ExerciseType::class,
            parentColumns = ["exerciseTypeId"],
            childColumns = ["exerciseTypeId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Equipment::class,
            parentColumns = ["equipmentId"],
            childColumns = ["equipmentId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Muscle::class,
            parentColumns = ["muscleId"],
            childColumns = ["muscleId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
@Parcelize
data class Exercise(
    val exerciseName: String,
    val exerciseTypeId: Long,
    val equipmentId: Long,
    val muscleId: Long
) : BaseEntity, Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var exerciseId: Long = 0
}
```

Training

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "training_table",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Microcycle::class,
            parentColumns = ["microcycleId"],
            childColumns = ["microcycleId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.SET_NULL,
        )
    ]
)
@Parcelize
data class Training(
    val trainingName: String,
    var microcycleId: Long,
    val dayOfMicrocycle: Int
) : BaseEntity, Parcelable {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var trainingId: Long = 0
}
```

Relations:

SetAndSetType

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class SetAndSetType(
    @Embedded
    val set: Set,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "setTypeId",
        entity = SetType::class,
        entityColumn = "setTypeId"
    )
    val setType: SetType
) : Parcelable
```

ExerciseWithSets

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class ExerciseWithSets(
    @Embedded
    var exercise: Exercise,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "exerciseId",
        entity = Set::class,
        entityColumn = "exerciseId"
    )
    var sets: List<SetAndSetType> = listOf()
) : Parcelable
```

TrainingWithExerciseWithSets

```kotlin
@Parcelize
data class TrainingWithExerciseWithSets(
    @Embedded
    val training: Training,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "trainingId",
        entity = Set::class,
        entityColumn = "trainingId"
    )
    val sets: List<ExerciseWithSets>
) : Parcelable
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to these declarations and not maybe to a DAO query declared somewhere else? If you have @Dao interfaces please post their source code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error is generated when "TrainingWithExerciseWithSets" relation code is generated. Without this data class, everything works fine. 
This is the function code from my DAO.

`@Query("SELECT * FROM training_table ORDER BY trainingId")
    fun getTrainingWithExerciseWithSets(): LiveData<List<TrainingWithExerciseWithSets>> `

Comment: The room SDK, during the build task, checks the query syntax and if it finds that it doesn't return a value for each NOT NULL column of the bound object it returns exactly that error. In this case it looks like the query is not returning a value for the property 'exerciseName' which is not nullable. I'm pretty sure that if you declare it as String? and you set a default value (for example null), the error should disappear. That is not the solution of course, it is just to confirm my hypothesis.

Comment: Check the query in *_impl file generated by the framework. If you post it I can give it a look.

Comment: Changing to a String? nothing helped, so here I am sending the generated code for this function from TrainingDo_Impl: https://pastebin.com/XC2E2fhy